# Laravel PhpUnit Dependency Injection

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, dependency-injection, phpunit

I'm using Dependency injection to call custom services in Laravel and it works fine. But when i inject those dependencies into my Phpunit test case classes using interfaces, i receive the following error:

> Target [App\Services\Interfaces\CarServiceInterface] is not instantiable.

although the interface has been bound to the target concrete class in the provider correctly.
i've used different styles like injecting through the `__construct()` method, inject to test method or even calling the `app()` method, but none of them works.

The test file:

```
private $carService;

public function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->carService = app(CarServiceInterface::class);
}
```

The provider:

```
$this->app->bind(
    App\Services\Interfaces\CarServiceInterface::class,
    App\Services\CarService::class
);
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Where do you write your test? In unit test or in feature test section?

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI In unit tests

Comment: You need to write your test in feature test section, as it's inherited from a custom test case that has `CreatesApplication` trait in it.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI Well i moved the test to feature section, but i still receive the error.

Comment: Maybe you have an error in binding.

Comment: @BABAKASHRAFI I don't think so because the process is all fine while serving the application.

Comment: @Faramarz share your code/test please, I need to see the test. Also, what Container method are you using to bound it? you should be using `$this->app->bind(CarServiceInterface::class, $carServiceInstance);`

Comment: @matiaslauriti Codes added and yes that's what i'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i finally found the problem. Although all the given answers/suggesstion by others was also right.
My test case class was extending the wrong TestCase namespace. By changing it to `App\TestCase` it's got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your test in feature section as feature tests are inherited from laravel base test case and they have `CreatesApplication` trait. [Refer to here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing#the-creates-application-trait)

After that, you can simply get your concrete class instance using `app('Your abstract class namespace ')` method or `$this->app->make('Your abstract class namespace ')` in your test.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the wrong test approach.
Why do you need DI in a test class?!
In a test class you have to prepare and maybe bind/mock the required classes.
And then test your code.

Second part the error says the class are not bind correcly in spite of your assumption.

BTW, if you think I've missed sth, and you need DI, use `bind` or `singleton` method.

```php
$this->app->bind(CarServiceInterface::class, fn () => $exampleInstance);

//or 

$this->app->singleton(CarServiceInterface::class, fn () => $exampleInstance);
```

Now you can use container to access your interface like this without DI error:

```php
$this->app[CarServiceInterface::class]
//or
$this->app->make(CarServiceInterface::class)
//or
app(CarServiceInterface::class)
```